# How do I persist database connection and scope session to a tenant and how do I configure Laravel Fortify for tenant's user in laravel multi-tenancy?

Tags: laravel, database, session, multi-tenant

I'm working on a laravel multi-tenant set-up with subdomain and database per tenant without any package. Tenant sign up, database creation, migrations and assigning subdomain, login, etc, all work.

The problem I'm faced with is how to:

1. properly configure Laravel Fortify for tenant's users' registration, email verification, password reset and login.
2. scope sessions to use the sessions table in each tenant's database, not the table in the main database.

My expectation is that a specific tenant's database is mapped to their subdomain (URL) once the tenant instance of the app is resolved, and tenant's user registration and authentication uses this database by default.

But in my attempt to register a user on a tenant subdomain, I still have to retrieve the tenant's database from the session and set my database config in my Fortify Actions class to create a tenant's user, otherwise I get a no database found error.

With this, the registration succeeds but the redirect to the dashboard fails because authentication attempt is on the main database not the tenant's. The session information also shows up on the main sessions table not the tenant's.

These are some of my codes:

TenantServiceProvider:

```
class TenantServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $manager = new TenantManager;

        $this->app->instance(TenantManager::class, $manager);
        $this->app->bind(Tenant::class, function () use ($manager) {
            return $manager->getTenant();
        });

 
        $this->app['db']->extend('tenant', function ($config, $name) use ($manager) {
            $tenant = $manager->getTenant();


            if ($tenant) {
                $config['database'] = 'tenant_' . $tenant->id;
            }
            
            return $this->app['db.factory']->make($config, $name);
        });

   
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

TenantManager:

```
class TenantManager {
    /*
     * @var null|App\Models\Tenant
     */
    private $tenant;
   
    public function setTenant(?Tenant $tenant)
    {
        $this->tenant = $tenant;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getTenant(): ?Tenant
    {
        return $this-tenant;
    }
    
    public function loadTenant(string $identifier, bool $subdomain): bool
    {
        $tenant = Tenant::query()->where($subdomain ? 'subdomain' : 'domain', '=', $identifier)->first();
    
        if ($tenant) {
            $this->setTenant($tenant);
            return true;
        }
        
        return false;
    }
 }
```

Tenant Middleware:

```
class IdentifyTenant
{
    /**
    * @var App\Services\TenantManager
    */
    protected $tenantManager;
    
    public function __construct(TenantManager $tenantManager)
    {
        $this->tenantManager = $tenantManager;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $host = $request->getHost();
        $pos = strpos($host, env('TENANT_DOMAIN'));
        
        if ($this->tenantManager->loadTenant($pos !== false ? substr($host, 0, $pos - 1) : $host, $pos !== false)) {
            $owner = $this->tenantManager->getTenant();
            Session::put('tenant', $tenant);

            return $next($request);
        }
        
        throw new NotFoundHttpException;
    }
}
```

Create User file:

```
class CreateNewEndUser implements CreatesNewUsers
{
    use PasswordValidationRules;

    /**
     * Create a newly registered end user.
     *
     * @param  array  $input
     * @return \App\Models\Owner\EndUser
     */
    public function create(array $input)
    {
        $database = session('tenant')->database;
        config(['database.connections.tenant.database' => $database]);
        DB::purge('tenant');
        DB::reconnect('tenant');

        Validator::make($input, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:owner.end_users'],
            'password' => $this->passwordRules(),
            'terms' => Jetstream::hasTermsAndPrivacyPolicyFeature() ? ['required', 'accepted'] : '',
        ])->validate();

        return EndUser::create([
            'name' => $input['name'],
            'email' => $input['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($input['password']),
        ]);
    }

}
```

fortify.php file:

```
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Fortify Guard
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which authentication guard Fortify will use while
    | authenticating users. This value should correspond with one of your
    | guards that is already present in your "auth" configuration file.
    |
    */

    'guard' => 'web',
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Fortify Password Broker
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which password broker Fortify can use when a user
    | is resetting their password. This configured value should match one
    | of your password brokers setup in your "auth" configuration file.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => 'users',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Username / Email
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value defines which model attribute should be considered as your
    | application's "username" field. Typically, this might be the email
    | address of the users but you are free to change this value here.
    |
    | Out of the box, Fortify expects forgot password and reset password
    | requests to have a field named 'email'. If the application uses
    | another name for the field you may define it below as needed.
    |
    */

    'username' => 'email',

    'email' => 'email',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Home Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure the path where users will get redirected during
    | authentication or password reset when the operations are successful
    | and the user is authenticated. You are free to change this value.
    |
    */

    'home' => RouteServiceProvider::HOME,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Fortify Routes Prefix / Subdomain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which prefix Fortify will assign to all the routes
    | that it registers with the application. If necessary, you may change
    | subdomain under which all of the Fortify routes will be available.
    |
    */

    'prefix' => '',

    'domain' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Fortify Routes Middleware
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which middleware Fortify will assign to the routes
    | that it registers with the application. If necessary, you may change
    | these middleware but typically this provided default is preferred.
    |
    */

    'middleware' => ['web'],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Rate Limiting
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By default, Fortify will throttle logins to five requests per minute for
    | every email and IP address combination. However, if you would like to
    | specify a custom rate limiter to call then you may specify it here.
    |
    */

    'limiters' => [
        'login' => 'login',
        'two-factor' => 'two-factor',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register View Routes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify if the routes returning views should be disabled as
    | you may not need them when building your own application. This may be
    | especially true if you're writing a custom single-page application.
    |
    */

    'views' => true,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Features
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Some of the Fortify features are optional. You may disable the features
    | by removing them from this array. You're free to only remove some of
    | these features or you can even remove all of these if you need to.
    |
    */

    'features' => [
        Features::registration(),
        Features::resetPasswords(),
        Features::emailVerification(),
        Features::updateProfileInformation(),
        Features::updatePasswords(),
        Features::twoFactorAuthentication([
            'confirmPassword' => true,
        ]),
    ],

];
```

auth.php file:

```
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],

        'end_user' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'end_users',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        'end_users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Tenant\EndUser::class,
        ],

        // 'end_users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'end_users',
        //     'model' => App\Models\Tenant\EndUser::class,
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],

        'end_users' => [
            'provider' => 'end_users',
            'table' => 'end_user_password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Confirmation Timeout
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define the amount of seconds before a password confirmation
    | times out and the user is prompted to re-enter their password via the
    | confirmation screen. By default, the timeout lasts for three hours.
    |
    */

    'password_timeout' => 3600,

];
```

Thanks.